# Button animation on view model property change?

Tags: wpf, animation

I have the following xaml code. The XAML displays an animation on the button whenever the button is click. I want to start/stop the animation whenever a boolean property in the view model is changed. Any help is appreciated in advance.

```
<Button Name="button5" Width="100" Margin="10" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="0" To="94" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="5x" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
            <Button.Content>
                <Grid Width="94">
                    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="0" Name="myBorder">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush>
                                <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0.115" Color="Black" />
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0.715" Color="Red" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                    </Border>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Search</TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
```

Also how can i animate the button in such a way that once the border width has reached its max width a reverse animation should occur. I mean i want a wave like effect(using gradient) inside the button. The wave should turn back once it hits the rightmost end of the button. Same should repeat indefinitely. This animation will be controlled using a ViewModel boolean property.

Comment: Did you fire out how to do this? I'm trying to animate an image whenever a property changes, and I can't figure out how.